# Jooq + hikariCP + Postgres - cannot handle failovers

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, hikaricp

I have a spring boot app that read/writes to postgres database. I use `jooq` and `hikariCP` to manage the database connections. My apps is connected to a patroni cluster consisting of two `Postgresql 14.5` instances - one is the master and the other one is a read-only replica.

When the service is processing data and I trigger a failover in the database -
killing the leader, choosing new leader, then changing the old leader to a replica - I start getting exceptions like

```
with\norg.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [delete from \"public\".\"my_table\" where \"public\".\"my_table\".\"username\" = ?]; ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
```

it looks like a `hikariCP/jdbc` driver issue where it is still using the connections to the `old-master-now-replica` instead of evicting them and creating new connections to the new leader.

How to solve it ?

My configuration looks like this:

```
org.jooq:jooq:3.16.10
org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0
org.jooq:jooq-postgres-extensions:3.16.10
com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3
```

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    banner-mode: "off"
  jooq:
    sql-dialect: Postgres
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://my-db-cluster:5432/my-database?tcpKeepAlive=true&ApplicationName=my-app"
    username: ${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
      minimumIdle: 0
      maximumPoolSize: 10
      auto-commit: false
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Could it be that the new selected leader is still read-only? Because a connection to the old failed over database server by the connection pool would not be possible at all, right? Then another exception would occur, like e.g. ConnectionTimeoutException. How do you know that the old database server was still used?

Comment: Furthermore, why don't you write all your database servers in the JDBC url like [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255008)? When you utilize a url to a database cluster  as you did then I would suppose your database cluster has the job to handle the outage and to swap it accordingly and then the connection pool has nothing to do because they point still to this very database cluster in which the magic happens.

Comment: No the new elected leader is definitely not a read-only - when I restart the service (which also closes all the existing connections) - the problem is solved and the service works with new connections

Comment: > why don't you write all your database servers
I could but I wanted to have only one db dns which would automatically load balance the traffic to the new master (which it does)

Comment: But the JDBC url points to the load balancer which in turn all the connections of the pool are using. So why should then any connection point to the old master when they actually point to the load balancer who dispatches it to the new leader? Then I would say your load balancer is the point of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding `&targetServerType=primary` to jdbc url as docs states: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/